# When attempting to initiate two or more Spring Batch jobs simultaneously, an error is thrown: ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-batch

I encounter an error when attempting to run two Spring Batch jobs in parallel using CompletableFuture. The error message is as follows:

```
OriginalSql = INSERT INTO BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE(JOB_INSTANCE_ID, JOB_NAME, JOB_KEY, VERSION)
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
, Error Msg = ORA-08177: can't serialize access for this transaction
```

I am using Spring Batch 5.x, Spring Boot 3.1.6, JDK 17

application.properties

```
spring.batch.repository.isolationlevelforcreate=ISOLATION_READ_COMMITTED
spring.batch.isolationlevel=READ_COMMITTED
spring.batch.jdbc.table-prefix=BATCH_
spring.batch.job.enabled=false
```

BatchConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfig {

@Bean("simpletaskExecutor")
    public TaskExecutor simpletaskExecutor() {
        SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor asyncTaskExecutor = new SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor("simpletaskExecutor");
        asyncTaskExecutor.setConcurrencyLimit(concurrencyCount);
        return asyncTaskExecutor;
    }


@Bean("jobLauncherAsync")
    @Scope("prototype")
    public JobLauncher jobLauncherAsync(DataSource dataSource, JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {

        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpletaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }
    
    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    }
    
    @Bean
    public BatchJobExecutionListener batchJobExecutionListener() {
        return new BatchJobExecutionListener();
    } 
    
    @Bean
    public BatchJobStepExecutionListner batchJobStepExecutionListner() {
        return new BatchJobStepExecutionListner();
    }
```

}

EmployeeJobConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Import(BatchConfig.class)
public class EmployeeJobConfig{
    
        
    @Autowired
    EmployeeStatusWritter employeeStatusWritter;
    
    @Autowired
    EmployeePendingProcessor employeePendingProcessor;
    
    
    
    @Bean("EmployeePendingReader")
    public JpaPagingItemReader<Employee> employeePendingReader(DataSource ds,EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        
        JpaPagingItemReader<Employee> jpaReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
        jpaReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        jpaReader.setQueryString("SELECT e FROM Employee e");
        jpaReader.setPageSize(5000);
        return jpaReader;

    }
    
    @Bean("EmployeeSPInvokeStep")
    public Step employeeSPInvokeStep(@Qualifier("EmployeePendingReader") ItemReader<Employee> reader,
            @Qualifier("employeeStatusWritter") ItemWriter<Employee> writer,
            @Qualifier("employeePendingProcessor") ItemProcessor<Employee, Employee> processor,JobRepository jobRepository,
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,BatchJobStepExecutionListner batchJobStepExecutionListner,TaskExecutor simpletaskExecutor) {

        return new StepBuilder("EmployeeSPInvokeStep",jobRepository)
                .<Employee, Employee>chunk(50,transactionManager).reader(reader)
                .processor(processor).writer(writer)
                .listener(batchJobStepExecutionListner)
                .taskExecutor(simpletaskExecutor)
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean("EmployeeSPJob")
    public Job employeeSPJob(@Qualifier("EmployeeSPInvokeStep") Step EmployeeSPInvokeStep,JobRepository jobRepository,BatchJobExecutionListener batchJobExecutionListener) {
        return new JobBuilder("EmployeeSPJob",jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(batchJobExecutionListener)
                .start(EmployeeSPInvokeStep)
                .build();
    }

}
```

ManagerConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@Import(BatchConfig.class)
public class ManagerConfig {
    
        

    @Autowired
    ManagerStatusWritter managerStatusWritter;
    
    
    @Autowired
    ManagerPendingProcessor managerPendingProcessor;
    
    @Bean("ManagerPendingReader")
    public JpaPagingItemReader<Manager> managerPendingReader(DataSource ds,EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        
        JpaPagingItemReader<Manager> jpaReader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
        jpaReader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        jpaReader.setQueryString("SELECT m FROM Manager m");
        jpaReader.setPageSize(5000);
        return jpaReader;

    }
    
    @Bean("ManagerSPInvokeStep")
    public Step indvInvoiceConsCtlSPInvokeStep(@Qualifier("ManagerPendingReader") ItemReader<Manager> reader,
            @Qualifier("ManagerStatusWritter") ItemWriter<Manager> writer,
            @Qualifier("managerPendingProcessor") ItemProcessor<Manager, Manager> processor,JobRepository jobRepository,
            PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager,BatchJobStepExecutionListner batchJobStepExecutionListner,TaskExecutor simpletaskExecutor) {

        return new StepBuilder("ManagerSPInvokeStep",jobRepository)
                .<Manager, Manager>chunk(5000,transactionManager).reader(reader)
                .processor(processor).writer(writer)
                .listener(batchJobStepExecutionListner)
                .taskExecutor(simpletaskExecutor)
                .build();
    }
    
    @Bean("ManagerSPJob")
    public Job ManagerSPJob(@Qualifier("ManagerSPInvokeStep") Step indvInvoiceConsCtlSPInvokeStep,JobRepository jobRepository,BatchJobExecutionListener batchJobExecutionListener) {
        return new JobBuilder("ManagerSPJob",jobRepository)
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(batchJobExecutionListener)
                .start(indvInvoiceConsCtlSPInvokeStep)
                .build();
    }
    
}
```

BatchJobManager.java

```
@Service
public class BatchJobManager {

    
    
      @Autowired ApplicationContext context;
     
      @Autowired BatchExecutorService batchExecutorService;
      
      @Autowired
      BatchJobRunner batchJobRunner;
      
       
    
    public void startJob() {
        
         try {
               System.out.println("BatchJobManager called .. "+new Date());
                
               String[] invoiceNames={"EmployeeSPJob","ManagerSPJob"};
               
               List<String> invoiceNamesList = Arrays.asList(invoiceNames);
               launchAsyn(getBatchJobList(invoiceNamesList));
                
                 
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("While loading job..");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }
        
    }
      

    public List<BatchJob>  getBatchJobList(List<String> jobNames) throws Exception{
        List<BatchJob> batchJobList=new ArrayList<BatchJob>();
        for(String job:jobNames) {
             BatchJob batchJob= BatchJob.builder().jobName(invoiceJob).build();
             batchJobList.add(batchJob);
        }
        return batchJobList;
    }
      
    
       
    public void launchAsyn( List<BatchJob> batchJobList) throws Exception{
         List<CompletableFuture<BatchJob>> batchJobFutureList = new ArrayList<CompletableFuture<BatchJob>>();
          
          for(BatchJob batchJob:batchJobList) {
          CompletableFuture<BatchJob> jobFuture = batchExecutorService.execute(batchJob, asyncTaskExecutor);
          batchJobFutureList.add(jobFuture);
          }
          
          CompletableFuture<Void> jobFutureResult = CompletableFuture
                    .allOf(batchJobFutureList.toArray(new CompletableFuture[batchJobFutureList.size()]));
          
          
          CompletableFuture<List<CanBatchJob>> allCompletableFuture = jobFutureResult.thenApply(future -> {
                return batchJobFutureList.stream().map(completableFuture -> completableFuture.join())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
            });
        
          List<BatchJob> resultFutureList=allCompletableFuture.get();
          
          for(BatchJob batch:resultFutureList) {
              System.out.println("Status "+batch.getIsCompleted());
          }
    }
   
    
}
```

BatchExecutorService.java

```
@Service
public class BatchExecutorService {
    
        
    @Autowired 
    BatchJobRunner batchJobRunner;
        
    public CompletableFuture<CanBatchJob> execute(CanBatchJob canBatchJob,TaskExecutor threadPoolTaskExecutor){
        return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> batchJobRunner.execute(canBatchJob),threadPoolTaskExecutor);
    }
    
    
}
```

BatchJobRunner.java

```
@Service
public class BatchJobRunner {

    @Autowired ApplicationContext context;
      
    
     @Autowired 
     @Qualifier("jobLauncherAsync")
     JobLauncher jobLauncherAsync;
    
    
    /*
     * @Autowired JobLauncher jobLauncherAsync;
     */
    
    public BatchJob execute(BatchJob batchJob) {
        try {
            System.out.println(" batchJob"+batchJob.getJobName()+" called ...");
            jobLauncherAsync.run(getJob(batchJob.getJobName()), getJobParameters(batchJob.getJobName()));
            Thread.sleep(15000);
            batchJob.setIsCompleted(true);
            System.out.println(" batchJob"+batchJob.getJobName()+" completed ...");
        }
        catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception "+e.getMessage());
            batchJob.setErrorDesc(e.getMessage().toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return canBatchJob;
    }
    
    public Job getJob(String jobName) {
        
         return  (Job) context.getBean(jobName); 
    }
    
    public JobParameters getJobParameters(String jobName) {
    
    JobParameters  jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder() .addString("UNIQUE_ID",
              UUID.randomUUID().toString(), true) .addString("JOB_NAME", jobName,
              true) .addDate("EXECUTION_START_DATE", Date.from(Instant.now()),
              true).toJobParameters();
    return jobParameters;
    }
    
}
```

BatchJob.java

```
public class BatchJob {

    private String jobName;
    private Boolean isCompleted;
    private String errorDesc;
    
    
}
```

The job runs successfully when executed one by one or in a sequential manner. However, when using CompletableFuture, it encounters issues.Is initiating Spring batch jobs simultaneously the correct approach?

Comment: I would remove the configuration for the isolation levels and next to that you are working hard to add additional async exection. The `JobLauncher` already launches jobs async. For monitoring you can check the job status from Spring Batch, you don't need to do a `Thread.sleep` and assume it is finished. You are adding layers of complexity that aren't needed.

Comment: @M.Deinum - you mean to say CompletableFuture not required here , just run the job one by one ?

Comment: The `JobLauncher` already uses the `TaskExecutor` to launch jobs in parallel, so all that additional cruft you added isn't needed. The `JobLauncher` doesn't need to be a `prototype` scoped bean either. Also the information in your `BatchJob` is already persisted in the tables from Spring Batch, you can retrieve it all from there already. In short you can just call `JobLauncher.run(job, parameters)` without anything else. After that you can query the tables after finishing for the status.

Answer (score 0):

1.Added given below property into application.properties

spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true

2.updated the jobLauncher() as given below in  BatchConfig.java

```
@Bean("jobLauncher")
    public JobLauncher jobLauncher(DataSource dataSource, JobRepository jobRepository) throws Exception {
        TaskExecutorJobLauncher jobLauncher = new TaskExecutorJobLauncher();
        jobLauncher.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
        jobLauncher.setTaskExecutor(simpletaskExecutor());
        jobLauncher.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jobLauncher;
    }
```

3. Removed CompletableFuture.
4. Removed BatchExecutorService.java
5. Added given below method in BatchJobManager.java to invoke jobs.

   ```
   public void launchSync(List<BatchJob> batchJobList) throws Exception {
            for(BatchJob batchJob:batchJobList) {
                 batchJobRunner.execute(batchJob);
                 }  
        }
   ```